# openerp: action to call a method on all ids selected in a tree view

Tags: odoo

I want to create an action which will call a method on a model passing the ids of the selected rows in a tree view, so that the action is available in the right hand part of the screen when items are selected. Is this possible to do this without creating a wizard with a single 'ok' button ?

Typically, I would like to be able to call the button_upgrade method of ir.module.module to update several modules at once, but this would be useful for many cases in the application.

I'm using OpenERP 6.1 and the web client.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in 5.0 with an [old-style wizard](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/main/view/3025/promise_date/wizard/wizard_sanity_checked.py), but I haven't seen a way to do it in 6.1 web client, yet. You can still use the old-style wizard in 6.1 GTK client, but it doesn't work in the web client.

You could pipe fortune messages into the OK dialog to entertain your users, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have v6, but this works in v7:

```
<record id="action_id_name" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Name that shows in More button</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_blah_blah"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">self.some_custom_code(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'), ..., context=context)</field>
</record>

<record id="value_id_name" model="ir.values">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    <field name="action_id" ref="action_id_name"/>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('action_id_name'))"/>
    <field name="key">action</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_blah_blah"/>
    <field name="model">blah.blah</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
</record>

def some_custom_code(self, cursor, uid, ids, ..., context):
    # possibly do some processing
    # maybe with the ... extra fields you added
    #
    # post your changes, either with an sql statement or by calling
    # self.write(...)
    return True
```

The names that you should replace with actual values:

- `action_id_name`: the id for your action record
- `Name that shows in More button`: whatever you want to show in the  button
- `model_blah_blah`: the name of the model used (should match whatever is found in your `security/ir.model.access.csv` file)
- `some_custom_code`: the name of the function in your model
- `value_id_name`: the id of your action's value record
- `Name`: a name (not sure where it shows up)
- `blah.blah`: the name your `model` and `table` in OpenERP notation
- `...`: any extra arguments/parameters you add

Comment: Note:  I adapted from the [answer found on OpenERP's site](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/action-server-multi-checkbox-select-39058).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working:

1. Create a new **Server Action**, at Settings » Customization » Low Level Objects » Actions » Server Actions:

   - **Action Name**: "Upgrade Selected Modules"
   - **Object**: ir.module.module
   - **Action Type**: Python Code
   - **Python Code**: action = obj.button_upgrade(context=context)
2. Create a new **Action Binding**, at Settings » Customization » Low Level Objects » Actions » Action Bindings:

   - **Name**: "Upgrade Modules action binding"
   - **Model name**: ir.module.module
   - **Qualifier**: client_action_multi
   - **Action**: search for "Upgrade Selected Modules" in the "Action (change only)" box. You should get the Action Reference field with something like: "ir.actions.server,680".

The forum topic ["Action : how to get selected rows ?"](http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic24211.html) was used as a reference.
You might also find interesting the [Email Template's button](http://fossies.org/dox/openerp-6.1-1/email__template_8py_source.html#l00175) automating the creation of an action to do mass mailings using the defined email template.

Comment: design-wise this is very ugly (not your fault at all). I'll give it a go, and report back.

Comment: Why do you think this is uglier than most things in OpenERP, @gurneyalex? To me, this is roughly similar to the way you configure a wizard. If you don't like configuring it through the Low Level Objects menu, you can do equivalent things in a module's XML data files.

Comment: I'm really not fond of code stored in a string attribute and evaluated. It generally makes for difficult debugging. And these data can be problematic during migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an `execute` action.
[http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_4.html#actions](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_4.html#actions%20%22OpenERP%20Developer%20Manual%20-%20Actions)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but unfortunately, there is very little information on that page about 'execute' actions. To the point that I'm not even sure such a thing actually exists in OpenERP. in ir_actions.py there is nothing closely resembling 'execute' for an action type. I'll gladly accept a more detailed answer on that line.